# How do I conditionally add a space in a regex replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

When I woke up this morning, I didn’t know a stroke of regex. By the time I went to Mass, I’d been able to cobble together this regex to find occurrences of ‘Mph’ in an html document.

(?i)(?<=[\s|\d])mph+

If I run it against the following test data:

```
<div class="vsMph">
<p>95 Mph</p>
</div>
<div class="vsMph">
<p>95Mph</p>
</div>
```

It correctly matches:

```
‘ Mph’ and
‘Mph’
```

And equally correctly leaves the ‘vsMph’ alone, which is exactly what I want. Eventually, I'm going to use the same technique to match knots, ft, in, km and so on.

I’m executing this expression in in Sublime Text 3 using RegReplace and ultimately, what I hope to do is to use this regular expression to find all occurrences of ‘Mph’ preceded by a space or a digit and:

1. Enclose ‘Mph’ in `<abbr>` tags.
2. Add a space between the digit and the
       opening `<abbr>` tag if there was no space between the last digit and
       'Mph' originally.

In other words, I want to convert the above test data to:

```
<div class="vsMph">
<p>95 <abbr title="Miles per hour">Mph</abbr></p>
</div>
<div class="vsMph">
<p>95 <abbr title="Miles per hour">Mph</abbr></p>
</div>
```

I can get RegReplace to add the `<abbr>` tags as described in 1. above, but I’ve searched around on Google and I can’t find anything that tells me how to conditionally insert a space in a regex replace.

So I’m wondering. Is it possible in the first place to conditionally add a space in a regex replacement and if so how do I do it, or do I have to search for ‘\sMph’ and ‘\dMph’ and replace them separately?

Regards.

Comment: Regex replace can't do this. Make two replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using groups to match `Mph`. You could search for simply the following regex:

```
(\d)(\s)?(Mph)
```

Then replace using groups

```
$1 <abbr title="Miles per hour">$3</abbr>
```

output:

```
<div class="vsMph">
<p>95 <abbr title="Miles per hour">Mph</abbr></p>
</div>
<div class="vsMph">
<p>95 <abbr title="Miles per hour">Mph</abbr></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim. I've had a play with this solution and all I had to do was to change $1 to \\1 and $3 to \\3 because I'm probably using a different regex dialect than you are.

Comment: I've now been able to modified the regex to:  

Find: `(<span class="subScript">)(.*)?(</span>)`
Replace: `<sub>\\2</sub>`    

and change:

    `V<span class="subScript">NO</span>` 
  
to:  
  
   ` V<sub>NO</sub>`

Comment: And this one to get all variations of 'Inches of mercury' Find: `(?i)(\d)(\s)?(in.hg|in. hg|” hg)` Replace `\1 <abbr title=\"Inches of mercury\">In.Hg</abbr>`. I think this is enough from me on this topic now. There are enough variations here to point future enquirers in the right direction and I'm unlikely to come up with any more. So thanks once again for your help Ibrahim. Over and out.

Comment: No problem, glad I can help @Pontiusthepilot, and glad to see the code works for you.